# How to download pdf file from url in node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm, download, nodemailer

I am creating an application to download pdf files from URLs and send them as an attachment using nodemailer.

I am using node.js with the express framework.

```
// Url of the image
            const file =  "https://picsum.photos/200/300"; //url path
            // Path at which image will get downloaded
            const filePath = `${__dirname}/files`;
            console.log(filePath);

            download(file, filePath)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('Download Completed');
                })
```

I am able to download the file and save it in a folder. But is there any other way to directly save into a variable without storing it in any folder?

Answer (score 0):

1. `npm install request`
2. 

```
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');

request.get(URL_PDF)
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('nom_du_fichier.pdf'))
  .on('finish', function() {
    console.log('Le fichier a été téléchargé et enregistré avec succès.');
  });
```

Comment: The file is corrupted  after  downloading and i don't want it to save in my local. Can i store it a variabale ?